# Finding how much time it takes for a complete Earth revolution around the Sun

Tags: orbital-motion, time, astronomy, earth, sun

Long story short, my brother made a joke about how stupid it is to celebrate the Earth making one "trip" around the Sun: New Year's Eve.

So I got curious and was wondering: how could the first physicists guess that a revolution of the Earth around the Sun takes 365.25xxx days?

I've tried my luck on the internet but didn't find anything simple enough to understand. I've read about Kepler's law, and there are nice formulas, but how does he work this out? And how could the first people who knew that Earth was revolving around the Sun guess how much time an entire revolution took?

I asked my brother and he told me if he'd have to do it, he would simply watch the stars and map them, do that every night, and count the days until he came back to the exact same position of the first night. Is that realistic?

Comment: There are quite a few different ways to define a year, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year#Astronomical_years

Comment: I've removed some comments that should have been posted as answers, and debates about their correctness.  Please use comments to suggest improvements to the question, and use answers to answer the question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In ancient civilizations, astronomy was a serious business (among other reasons, to accurately predict the seasons), so there were a lot of scientists making very careful measurements. Even with the naked eye, you can make quite accurate observations, and the ancients used these observations well.

The first really accurate determination of the length of the year was made by Hipparchus, a Greek astronomer who lived circa 190-120 BC. He calculated a year to be `365 + 1/4 - 1/300` (365.24667) days long, which is 6 minutes/year longer than the current estimate. Before that time, most people used 365.25, which is also not too far off (11 minutes), but is likely also due to the lucky coincidence the actual value is so near the neat round 1/4 day.

Hipparchus mostly used exact measuring of the equinoxes (the moment day and night are just as long, and when the Sun rises exactly in the east and sets exactly in the west). It's possible to measure this quite exactly, up to an hour. But Hipparchus also used the data gathered by earlier astronomers, back until 432 BC (~300 years before him). When you have this large time-span, and combine multiple measurements to cancel out any errors, it's thus possible to get very accurate results. Oh, and he used solar eclipses to refine his measurements as well, though the equinoxes were more important (there are more of them).

Incidentally, he was also the first one to discredit your question ;-)

That is, what most people think of as "a year", is actually *not* the time it takes the Earth to complete one orbit around the Sun. It's very close, but the Earth also precesses: it's top (the poles) very slightly turn around. It also means that Polaris (our current "northern pole star") will not remain the northern pole star forever (but it will for several thousand years). This also means that the time from equinox to equinox is not exactly the same as the time it takes the Earth to complete an orbit, it is shorter by 20 minutes and 24.5 seconds.

The time it takes the Earth to complete an orbit is called a *sidereal year*, but the time it takes for the equinoxes to repeat (and thus the seasons), is called a *tropical year*. Strictly speaking, "a year" could refer to both of them, but most of the time a tropical year is meant. And a tropical year is also what our calendar is based on.

At least, the western calendar uses a value of 365.2425 days, while the modern established value for a tropical year is 365.24219 days (27 seconds shorter), and a sidereal year is 365.256 36 days (1197.5 seconds longer)
These values are all assuming a day is exactly 86400 SI seconds, without any leap seconds.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how precession changes how long it takes the Earth to complete an orbit around the sun?  I am having a hard time seeing how a wobbly axis could either change the length of a day or the speed at which the Earth orbits the sun - and 20+ minutes/year seems like a big difference.

Comment: Great explanation I loved it ! out of curiosity, did Hipparchus know that Earth was actually going around the sun, and not the opposite ?

Comment: @Michael Precession affects equinoxes (tropical year) as the exact point that the Earth's axis is perpendicular with the line to the sun slowly changes over time. As you say, the sidereal year is unaffected.

Comment: @Loïc Geocentric vs Heliocentric doesn't matter here. Equinox to equinox is the same either way.

Comment: @Loic I don't know if he was a proponant of heliocentrism or geocentrism (and as jaxadl0127 pointed out, it makes no difference here). The only thing I can find is that the idea of heliocentrism was introduced, but not widely accepted at his time.

Answer (score 29):

Observe where the Sun rises and sets, and how high it gets in the sky at midday. These things repeat after 365 days.

Comment: what about observing the constellations, would it be feasible to guess the revolution of the Earth around the Sun this way ?

Comment: Yes, but isn’t it easier to notice the big bright thing?

Comment: Early civilizations figured this out long before there was anything called physics. They needed to understand things like this to know when to plant crops.

Comment: @G.Smith the early civilizations didn't know that the Earth goes around the Sun, though. They simply knew that 365 days is the duration of the cycle of seasons, which could be checked by observations of the Sun.

Comment: This doesn't work in the equator, does it?

Comment: 365 is fine, but I'm really curious regarding the precision of experiments (conducted _by ancient men_, this way) to infer about the remaining 6 hours and a few minutes, especially if it takes ancient people a few minutes itself in recording/jotting their "observations". e.g. using this method, how precisely can you say that 1 orbit is 365 days, 365 days & 5 hours, versus 365 days & 6 hours, 365 days, 6 hours & 5 minutes ... Also, the Sun is extended, so would there be a discernable amount of difference between the last two, which ancient men could be sure of? (Notice that OP says 365.25xx d).

Comment: @Loïc you can do one or the other (watch the sun moving over the sky or the constellations) and you will get different results - the tropical year in the first case, the sidereal year in the other. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year#Sidereal,_tropical,_and_anomalistic_years

Comment: @justhalf it does, There is about 50° difference where the sun is. at the extremes. You'll notice when a shadow grows to 1 side of a tree and then moves to the other.

Comment: @justhalf: It works everywhere. See [here] for example.

Comment: Ooh, I just knew that. Something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_path#/media/File:Solstice-0.jpg)? I live near the equator but feel like nobody is talking about the different position of the sun.

Comment: @justhalf yes, because the Earth is tilted. The sun goes from one tropic to the other and yes, its tilt changes at the equator.

Comment: I'm sorry about removing this as an accepted answer, it clearly is clever and interesting, but the answer from Emil is much more complete and interesting.
Sadly I can't accept both, I would accept a lot on this topic. But you have my vote up.

Comment: No problem, and no need to apologize.

Comment: @299792458: See the last paragraph in my [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/516609/finding-how-much-time-it-takes-for-a-complete-earth-revolution-around-the-sun/516727#516727). The pattern doesn't repeat after 365 days. It repeats after 1461 days.

Answer (score 16):

If you would capture sun position in the sky at the same time each day of year - you would get a periodic figure, called [Analemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analemma) which shows sun's path in a sky through a whole year :

[image]

Comment: @usernumber I believe he means the position along the horizon where the sun rises and sets. As viewed from a consistent location on earth's surface, changes over the course of the year, but once you go a full year, it'll be back where you started and the oscillation will begin again.

Comment: @usernumber See my edit,- I've changed my explanation to be more "down to Earth"

Comment: Oh, I get it. In the image, some parts of the analemma are less densly sampled than others. Is this because the sun goes through the analemma at a non-constant speed, or is it observational bias (perhaps due to cloudy days?)

Comment: @usernumber, yes seems there are gaps in curve, so I suspect there was some weather problems, cloudy days or other reasons skipping measurements. Other than that, number of points in lower loop is approximately equal to number of points in upper loop, which is $\approx 25$. However average distance between points in upper loop is a bit smaller than in lower loop, because figure is asymmetric.

Comment: This raises the additional question, how could the first physicists measure "the same time each day".

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yes, you need decent mechanical clocks whose accuracy is better than the planet's rotation from day to day, and a well-measured mean solar day to know when to record the position of the sun to make an analemma.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni The need to have clocks decoupled from the sun's movement is very old. First ancient such clocks operated on flow of liquid, thus "[water clocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_clock)". They have known to be existed even in ancient Egypt approximately 16th century BC. One of such water clocks which is called "[Tower of the Winds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_the_Winds)" was built by Andronicus of Cyrrhus around 50 BC in Greece and was even able to display the seasons of the year and astrological dates and periods.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni The simplest way to measure the same time each day is to track noon, which you can do just by looking at the sun. In essence, you can just stick a pole in the ground, and every day mark the tip of the shadow when the sun is at its highest, and doing it for 365 days will get you a drawing of the analemma.

Comment: @Peteris no, you won't. Solar highest altitude doesn't always happen at noon but it always happen when the sun crosses the meridian. You wouldn't get an "8" shaped analemma, you'd just get an "I" shape. See ["equation of time"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_time).

Comment: @Peteris: I just checked: [Here](https://i.imgur.com/gFiBorD.png), every day at 12:00 (winter time). [There](https://i.imgur.com/xH7BlEa.png), every day when the sun is highest.

Answer (score 9):

> I asked my friend, and he told me, if he'd have to do it, he would
>   simply watch at the stars, and map them, and do that until he came
>   back to the exact same position of the first night. Is that realistic
>   ? I don't think the position would differ so much that the eye could
>   see it. Am I right ?

## No light pollution

Please remember there was no light pollution at that time. It was possible to see more stars than today, they appeared brighter and more colorful. The [Milky Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way), [Andromeda Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda_Galaxy) and [Orion Nebula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_Nebula) were perfectly visible to the naked eye.

## Seasonal constellations

There are dozens of easy indicators in the night sky if you want to know the season:

- Arcturus, Spica, and Regulus form the [Spring Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Triangle).
- Altair, Deneb and Vega form the [Summer triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Triangle)
- Rigel, Aldebaran, Capella, Pollux, Procyon, and Sirius form the [Winter Hexagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_Hexagon).

With this information alone, it is possible to reliably tell the current month by simply looking at the night sky after sunset, without any instrument.

Accuracy could be improved by using a very bright star (e.g. Sirius) and clear reference points (e.g. a far-away mountain).

## Guardians of the pole star

You could use [Ursa Minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursa_Minor) and [Ursa Major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursa_Major) as an annual clock, with the [two guardians](https://earthsky.org/brightest-stars/kochab-and-pherkad-guard-the-north-celestial-pole) rotating around [Polaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaris). They do a full turn in a year, so an accuracy of 1° will give you an accuracy of ~1 day. It shouldn't be hard to measure with an [astrolabe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrolabe).

[image]

## Improving accuracy

You cannot expect high accuracy if you measure the thickness of a single sheet of paper with a ruler. You can improve it greatly if you stack 1000 sheets, measure the total height and divide it by 1000.

Patterns in star position will repeat after approximately 365 days, but they will repeat almost exactly after 4 revolutions in 1461 days, which gives $\frac{1461}{4} = 365.25$.
 With enough time and dedication, it's possible to improve the accuracy even further.

Comment: The answer for "How did early physicists...?" is very often "by looking at stars".

Answer (score 2):

It is not that simple. It takes tools such as Stonehenge to accurately time the passage of stars. You may then notice that the Sun's passage across the sky varies with a period of 365.25 days.

Comment: I'm pretty sure to measure the length of the year, only two fixed points are necessary. So take a tree, stand where the sunrise and the tree are aligned, place a stone where you stand. Check again next year.

Comment: @Christian Place a big, stable stone circle, such as Stonehenge, and keep people out. Put some scientist or priest in charge, preferable with guards. A tree is not a very good plan. It grows, changes shape, dies, is cut down, burns. Other trees block the view. Etc.

Comment: but building stonehege is hard. finding trees is easy. Depends on the precision you need.

Answer (score 2):

In order to find out how the topic evolved in the past 1000's of year, the proper search on the Internet is about the different calendar systems that people employed in the past.

Generally, calendars evolved between better and better precision and different attempts to fit the seasons and the moon phases around some easy calculatable numbers (12, 30, 360, etc...).

It was late in the process when people found out about the movement of the celestial bodies.

Answer (score -2):

It is a lot simpler. In Europe we have four seasons. The same season returns about 365 days later. Over time the measurement got more and more exact.

The reason we have seasons is that the earth axis is slightly inclined compared to the movement around the sun.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. There are so many fluctuations from one year to the other that I don't think it would be possible to time seasons more accurately than 1 or 2 weeks using weather alone.

Comment: i would call the inclination a bit more than "slight", it's over 20 degrees!

Comment: @EricDuminil If you know that, say, July 1st, 1919 was a summer day, and you know the count of days to July 1st, 2019, which falls into the 100th summer after that, you have already fixed the length of the year with a 0.25% accuracy, which is less than a day. You can get to your 2 weeks precision with an observation period of only 13 years using weather alone.

Comment: @notovny see cmaster comment above.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Apologies. Meant to direct the previous version of the comment to @cmaster :  Meteorological seasons, unless arbitrarily fixed to calendar dates, aren't anywhere near that regular in duration. The astronomical seasons are, but they don't care about the weather. The Groundhog's shadow may try to predict something for the meteorological seasons, but for the astronomical seasons, it's /always/ six more weeks of winter.

Comment: @notovny My point was: Take *any* day that feels like summer in 1919 and 2019, and you'll get your 0.25% accuracy for the length of the year. The first of July was just an example. You can greatly improve this method by taking an event that typically occurs within a shorter time frame than three month. The first frost could be a good one for my location: It's usually within the same 2 weeks time frame. By observing stars/sun, you basically do the same thing, using basic events with less variance. But you can get arbitrary precise with horribly variant events by using a long enough time span.